# Pygame with discord bot

Tags: python, discord

```
import discord
import random
import pygame
import time

client = discord.Client()
white = (255,255,255)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
green = (0,255,0)
red =(255,0,0)
black = (0,0,0)

global song
song = 0


@client.event
async def on_message(message):

        # we do not want the bot to reply to itself
    if message.author == client.user:
         return
     if message.content.startswith(''):
        while True:
            if song == 1:

                await client.send_message(message.channel, ';;play https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cUbFzEMQ2Fs')

            elif song == 2:
                await  client.send_message(message.channel, ';;play https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YlomIQF2zbI')
            else:
                await client.send_message(message.channel, "HI")
                pygame.quit()






def interface():



    pygame.init()
    gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

    def button(x, y, w, h, ac, ic, songs):
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        if x + w > mouse[0] > x and y + h > mouse[1] > y:
            pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ac, (x, y, w, h))
            if click[0] == 1 and songs != 0:

        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ic, (x, y, w, h))

    while True:
        event = pygame.event.get()
        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        button(50, 50, 50, 50, red, green, 1)
        button(50, 50, 50, 50, red, green, 2)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)











@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')
    interface()
    '''channel = client.get_channel('id')
    await client.join_voice_channel(channel)
    print('Bot should joined the Channel')'''


client.run('token')
```

Does anyone have any suggestion on how to do it as im a bit stuck.
I would like the bot say something when i click a button on the pygame display interface. Thank you for any help that you can give me,

Comment: You can look further into `threading`. And I would recommend you using tkinter since it's a built in GUI and very handy with buttons:)

Comment: Sorry but i have never used threading before

Comment: Well... in order to do this, you will need to use it since there's two event loops. The other way is to combine the two loops which is way more confusing and I will not recommend it and please edit your title to something future readers might search up. Something like "how to use a GUI with discord bot"

Comment: Is it hard to get to know how to use threading

Comment: No, it's pretty simple for starters, then gets more complicated the more advanced you get

Comment: If no one else answers your question later I'll attempt to test my theory since I have no way of testing anything without my computer

Comment: ok thank you for your help

Comment: See item #1 in http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, pointing to http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not exactly your code, it gaves to you the rough idea of using threading to run both of them at the same time. I explained everything through out the example. It will send a message to a selected channel when the square is pressed.

```
import discord, random, pygame, time, asyncio
import random # just for fun
from threading import Thread

### better to set them as a global variable
client = discord.Client()

pygame.init() # put these in the beginning
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
white = (255,255,255)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
green = (0,255,0)
red   = (255,0,0)
black = (0,0,0)
###
#client.send_message()
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # do what you want to do...
    pass

async def send_message(msg):
    await client.send_message(client.get_channel('197481285852069898'), msg) # send a message, you can use channel id or any channel instance

def run_gui(): # for running the gui
    gameDisplay.fill(white) # initialize the screen white
    current_color = red 
    my_rect = pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, current_color, (50,50,50,50)) # draw a rect and save the rect
    while 1: # pygame mainloop
        pygame.display.update() # update the screen
        for event in pygame.event.get(): # proper way of retrieving events
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN: # check if the event is right clicked on mouse 
                mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                if my_rect.collidepoint(mouse): # see if it pressed the rect
                    # do stuff if the button is pressed...
                    current_color = red
                    # send a random message maybe?
                    choosen = random.choice(['hello','hi','I am a bot','wassup','I luv u <3'])
                    asyncio.ensure_future(send_message( msg=choosen)) # since discord.py uses asyncio

                else:
                    # do stuff if it's not pressed...
                    current_color = green
                # refill the screen white
                gameDisplay.fill(white)
                # redraw the rect
                my_rect = pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, current_color, (50,50,50,50)) 

        clock.tick(60) # 60 fps

def run_bot(): # for running the bot
    client.run('token') # run the bot

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')

Thread(target=run_bot).start() # start thread the run the bot
run_gui() # run the gui
```