# How to connect discord and pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, discord.py

So a few days ago I watched this video of a guy making a 'discord game'. He did so by making a terminal game and then transferred it to discord. But it was in Java, so I started googling out and saw If I could do something similar in python. Although I could use a terminal game and then transfer it, I wanted to see if I could merge pygame and discord make a pygame in discord. I searched google and found this one answer. I thought of using but I wanted to ask if there is another way.

Here is the link to the form: [Pygame with discord bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42912253/pygame-with-discord-bot)

It uses threading in order to run both (discord API and pygame) at the same time.

```
import discord, random, pygame, time, asyncio
import random # just for fun
from threading import Thread

### better to set them as a global variable
client = discord.Client()

pygame.init() # put these in the beginning
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
white = (255,255,255)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
green = (0,255,0)
red   = (255,0,0)
black = (0,0,0)
###
#client.send_message()
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # do what you want to do...
    pass

async def send_message(msg):
    await client.send_message(client.get_channel('197481285852069898'), msg) # send a message, you can use channel id or any channel instance

def run_gui(): # for running the gui
    gameDisplay.fill(white) # initialize the screen white
    current_color = red 
    my_rect = pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, current_color, (50,50,50,50)) # draw a rect and save the rect
    while 1: # pygame mainloop
        pygame.display.update() # update the screen
        for event in pygame.event.get(): # proper way of retrieving events
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN: # check if the event is right clicked on mouse 
                mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                if my_rect.collidepoint(mouse): # see if it pressed the rect
                    # do stuff if the button is pressed...
                    current_color = red
                    # send a random message maybe?
                    choosen = random.choice(['hello','hi','I am a bot','wassup','I luv u <3'])
                    asyncio.ensure_future(send_message( msg=choosen)) # since discord.py uses asyncio

                else:
                    # do stuff if it's not pressed...
                    current_color = green
                # refill the screen white
                gameDisplay.fill(white)
                # redraw the rect
                my_rect = pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, current_color, (50,50,50,50)) 

        clock.tick(60) # 60 fps

def run_bot(): # for running the bot
    client.run('token') # run the bot

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')

Thread(target=run_bot).start() # start thread the run the bot
run_gui() # run the gui
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy to make more static type of games into a Discord bot however it's pretty hard to make a "faster paced" game into a Discord bot because of rate limiting (how many requests per specified periof of time you can make).

In your example the guy in the original thread only wanted to send messages when he clicked inside his game. Not make a full game into a Discord bot.

If you want to make something "fast paced" - meaning that the interface updates multiple times a second you're probably out of luck since Discord doesn't allow for that.